# The keyboard shortcuts no longer work (volume, play, etc)

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, kde, hotkeys, manjaro

The keyboard shortcuts for media control no longer work (volume, play, etc) on my distro (Manjaro KDE). Apparently, this happened after a update. I've tried several keyboard settings in ("System Settings" -> "Keyboard"), but nothing worked. Any suggestions, any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Fill a bugreport at https://bugs.manjaro.org/ if does not already exist.

Comment: I have already done this (https://forum.manjaro.org/t/the-keyboard-shortcuts-no-longer-work-volume-play-etc/12355). But, I imagine that this is a broader issue that can be generalized to any Linux. For that reason I also posted here. Thank you! @IporSircer

Comment: Then report it to kde developers: https://bugs.kde.org/

Comment: NOTE: I posted in the forum (https://forum.manjaro.org). And I'll post it on https://bugs.manjaro.org/ as well. @IporSircer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to remove the "xf86-input-joystick" package and reboot the computer. Tested on the Manjaro!

Answer (score 0):

One of the F keys at the top can be used to "lock" or disable the shortcut keys, on my keyboard (gamdias ares) it has a key that will toggle it, just search for it on your keyboard
P.S. hold down the FN key when you find it and press the toggle key

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I did not find this feature. Unfortunately this does not apply in my case.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that, are you using a usb keyboard or is it a laptop keyboard?

Comment: I don't know if you can do this on every laptop but supposedly you can go to the BIOS and disable the function keys and enable them.

Comment: http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02035108 this is for HP laptops but I think that every BIOS can do this, I'll do more research and try to find solutions for you

Comment: I'm using a usb keyboard. Thanks! @Doomed Space

Comment: Im also going to know just the brand, the model doesn't matter

Comment: Microsoft Wireless Comfort Keyboard 5000. @Doomed Space

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/microsoft-wireless-comfort-desktop-5000-function/5b907126-8ab4-4cd0-bc77-674c2bf8a05f

Here is some help with your problem

Comment: Sorry, but I use Linux (Manjaro Distro). @Doomed Space

Comment: So the key on your keyboard didn't work?

Comment: The hotkeys pointed at image does not work.

Comment: http://linux-drivers.net/index.php?p=keyboard&s=microsoft&j=Microsoft%20Wireless%20Comfort%20Desktop%205000%20USB%20(-%20Black,%20Ergo,%20--5,%20Roll)%20(CSD-00017)

That is the drivers list for your keyboard for linux, you just have to select which version of linux you have.

If that link doesn't work try this and select your keyboard
http://linux-drivers.net/index.php?p=keyboard&s=microsoft